# R: xgboost plot roc curve

Tags: r, plot, machine-learning

To plot roc curve:

```
library(ROCR)
<data cleaning/scrubbing>
<train data>
.....
.....
rf.perf = performance(rf.prediction, "tpr", "fpr") #for RF
logit.perf = performance (logit.prediction, "tpr", "fpr") #for logistic reg
tree.perf = performance(tree.prediction, "tpr", "fpr") #for cart tree
...
plot(re.perf) #a RF roc curve
```

If I want to run a `xgboost` classification and subsequently plotting roc:
objective = "binary:logistics"

I'm confused with the xgboost's arguments *metrics "auc"* (page 9 of the [CRAN manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xgboost/xgboost.pdf)), it says area. 
How does one plot the curve with tpr and fpr for model comparison?

I tried search the net and github, most emphasis on feature importance graph (for `xgboost`).

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, the AUC is the Area Under the Curve of the Receiver Operator Curve (ROC). This is a metric between 0-1. For me it is not entirely clear what you're question is. I guess you just want to plot the ROC but are having difficulties doing this? Maybe include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), that could help.

Answer (score 4):

Let me first talk about ROC curve

> The ROC curve is created by plotting the true positive rate (TPR) against the false positive rate (FPR) at various threshold settings.

In python it can be done easily as:

```
from sklearn import metrics
def buildROC(target_test,test_preds):
    fpr, tpr, threshold = metrics.roc_curve(target_test, test_preds)
    roc_auc = metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
    plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic')
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr, 'b', label = 'AUC = %0.2f' % roc_auc)
    plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')
    plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1],'r--')
    plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
    plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
    plt.gcf().savefig('roc.png')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWzW0.png)

For example in above image, at certain threshold and at cost of false positive rate 0.2, we can get true positive nearly 0.96 - 0.97

[A good documentation on ROC](http://gim.unmc.edu/dxtests/roc3.htm)